# $X^2 = XX^T$ or $X^2 = X^TX$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector.

Is $X^2 = XX^T$

or

$X^2 = X^TX$?

Is there a convention?

Edit: suppose one wants to compute the first term in variance $VX = E (X^2) - (EX)^2$.

Comment: I've never seen either.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote $X'$?

Comment: It’s neither. The notation $X^2$ is not used to apply to vectors.

Comment: What does $X'$ mean?

Comment: Maybe you mean $X\times X$ rather than $X^2$

Comment: I assume $X'$ is $X^T$ ("$X$ transpose").

Comment: @ArturoMagidin how about computing expectations?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, yes, it's transpose.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Regarding the OP's edit, the "$\mathbb{E}[X^2]$" analog for random vectors is $\mathbb{E}\left[XX'\right]$. Also the "$\E[X]^2$" part becomes $\E[X]\E[X]'$. In other words, the covariance matrix of a random vector is $\color{blue}{\mathrm{Var}(X)=\E[XX']- \boldsymbol{\mu}\boldsymbol{\mu}'}$, where $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\E[X]$.

Comment: @Cenlim: There’s a difference between a vector and a random variable. Vectors don’t get squared, at least not in **linear algebra**, which is what you tagged this. If you are talking about Probability, then tag it corectly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, there are random vectors. But thanks for suggestion about the tag.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth is it always the case that $X^2$ turns into $XX'$?

Comment: It’s called “context”. If you tag this linear algebra, and you just say “vector”, and you don’t explain what type of object you are talking about, or where and in what context you encountered this notation... did you expect people to read your mind? The government doesn’t like it when I do that without a properly issued judicial warrant...

Comment: @Cenlim This is just the *definition* of the variance-covariance matrix of a random vector $X$. There are several reasons why here it should be $XX'$ and not $X'X$. However, there may be other situations/contexts where $X'X$ may be the relevant quantity to look at.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I'm sorry for confusion. I thought there is some sort of universal convention about that.

Comment: By the way, the notation $X'$ for $X^T$ seems to be fairly common in statistical contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$In terms of variance-covariance matrix of a random vector (from OP), the formula is $\color{blue}{\mathrm{Var}(X) = \E\left[XX^T\right] - \boldsymbol{\mu}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T}$, where $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is the mean vector $\E[X]$. So in this context, $XX^T$ is the relevant analog of $X^2$ from the scalar case.

However, I do not think $X^2$ is universally defined as either $X^TX$ or as $XX^T$, and there may be different situations where different ones of these are the quantity to consider.

Comment: I've realized that if one looks at the definition $VX = E(X-\mu)(X-\mu)'$, then it becomes clear that squared is $XX'$.